# get request to txt file in assets folder | Angular 8

Tags: angular

I tried to make a get request to assets folder. I have there txt file. But I have always mistake "not found"

```
ngOnInit() {
this.apiService.getData().subscribe(
  suc => {
    console.log(suc);
  },
  err => {
  });
}
```

In my api services

```
 getData(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>('../assets/data.txt');
}
```

I tried many ways but without result.

```
getData(): Observable<any> {
return this.http.get<any>('src/app/assets/data.txt');
}
```

It always tried to make a request to localhost

```
GET https://localhost:44307/assets/data.txt 404
```

Comment: Try work out what path (url) gets the file directly in your browser. Then check if your API Service is making the same url call.

Comment: If you don't absolutely have to fetch it with rxjs, I think you could try to get it using "require". -> const data = require(path/to/your/file.txt)

Comment: Have you tried `this.http.get<any>(/assets/data.txt)`

Answer (score 0):

You have to put responseType: 'text' in your httpOptions.

See https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpRequest

Angular defaults to json so you have to tell it to parse it as plain text..

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
this.http.get('assets/data.txt', {responseType: 'text'})
    .subscribe(
        data => {
            console.log(data);
            }
        },
        error => {
            console.log(error);
        }
    );
```

Here is a similar [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-read-csv-file) which read from a csv file

Comment: The problem is that I always have request to api such url `https://localhost:44307/assets/data.txt 404`